# What are the differences between Counter Strike: Global Offensive and Counter Strike: Source?

Tags: version-differences, counter-strike-source, counter-strike-global-offensive

As *Counter Strike: Source* is also a graphics improved version of original *CS*.

But what are new features in *Global Offensive* and how they differs from *Counter Strike: Source*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mostly subjective, really. Some people like CS:S, some people don't. Here are some of the differences. CS:GO has:

- Smaller hitboxes
- Less clutter on maps to block movement
- Tighter recoil (spray and pray does not work well)
- New weapons (a few pistols, shotguns, smgs, mgs)
- New grenades (decoy and flame)
- Better graphics

Some actual improvements:

- Gungame and Deathmatch modes built into game
- Matchmaking
- Rating system
- Elo system
- Arranged team matchmaking
- CS:GO TV, a significant improvement over previous iterations.

Comment: what does CS:S have that CS:GO doesn't?

Comment: @Neffer_23 Nothing that I can think of. CS:GO is being continuously improved and has roughly 40 times more players. Unless you're on a very old computer or really fond of the oldschool gameplay, CS:GO is what you want at this point.

Comment: CS GO has better graphics and a lot of traffic. So if you use a laptop with moderate graphics card (I use Nvidia 750M), you should switch to CS:GO. Just in video settings, bring down the shadow settings to LOW.